# Define Nonconstant Boundary Conditions "partially" on an edge - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to define Dirichlet and Neumann conditions in a plain stress problem *only on part* of one of the edges of a plate.
Matlab's [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/nonconstant-boundary-object-specification.html) for defining nonconstant boundary conditions indicates that functions must be written such as:

```
applyBoundaryCondition(model,'edge',1,'r',@myrfun);
applyBoundaryCondition(model,'face',2,'g',@mygfun,'q',@myqfun);
applyBoundaryCondition(model,'edge',[3,4],'u',@myufun,'EquationIndex',[2,3]);
```

It moreover says that each function must have the following syntax.

```
function bcMatrix = myfun(region,state)
```

and finally that "**region**" is a structure containing the fields **region.x** (x-coordinate of the points), **region.y** (y-coordinate of the points), etc.  if there are Neumann conditions (which is my case), then solvers pass the following data in the region structure: **region.nx** — (x-component of the normal vector at the evaluation points), etc. My questions are:

1. From where can I get the structure **region**?
2. How can I pass the argument that boundary conditions apply in one part of one of the edges?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

@Oliver,

1) I think you don't need to make the structure `region`, but make functions that are capable of using it. Since the boundary condition generally depends on the location, you will need `region.x` and `region.y`.

2) You can use `region.x` and `region.y` to make boundary conditions dependent on the location. This is one way of applying them "partially" if the type of boundary condition is the same. Otherwise, you will have to define the split in the boundary explicitly. This happens probably while defining the geometry of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tvo! Would you mind sharing a hint on how to define the region.x and region.y please! I mean, I can't locate the coordinates of the nodes located on the edge..

Comment: @Oliver Hi, this data will be inside the PDE model object. You don't have to provide it, only use it. Have a look in the help-link in your qeustion. There are two options, depending on whether 'Vectorized' is on or off, the data in `region.x` and `region.y` will be single points or vectors of multiple points. It's up to you whether you want vectorization or not. If possible, use it, because it will be faster.

Comment: Sorry again, to what specific command you refer to in "vectorization"?

Comment: @Oliver Have a look at the Name-Value Pair Arguments in http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/applyboundarycondition.html